# Unable to establish connection over TLS 1.2 on AIX 7.1/7.2

Tags: java-8, tls1.2, aix

How to enable communication over TLS1.2 on AIX 7.1 or 7.2 with IBM JDK 1.8 latest update?

By default, the request is trying to establish a connection over TLSv1 even though TLS 1.2 is explicitly enabled on server as well as  on Java 8. The openssl command throws SSL handshake error. We tried with 2 versions of OpenSSL, 1.0.1e and 1.0.2k, but same behavior.

logs:

```
[06:24 AM root@s822-aix01p1 /opt]: openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect 10.225.120.125:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
804401144:error:14094438:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert internal error:s3_pkt.c:1259:SSL alert number 80
804401144:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:599:


no peer certificate available

No client certificate CA names sent

SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 0 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1550489753
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

It seems there is no cipher suites on common which can work for TLS 1.2.

Also, is there any way to enable TLS 1.1 & 1.2 in AIX? I have read few articles and got to know that these are not enabled  by default on AIX.

Comment: Does it work with if you use option `-ssl3` or `-tls1` in your `openssl s_client` command instead of `tls1_2`?

Comment: The handshake happens for sslv3. Also, if I enable TLSv1 on server side, handshake happens for that as well. I suspect TLSv1.2 ciphers are not enable in IBM java 8 by default, but I am unable to find any reference to enable TLS ciphers on IBM Java 8.

Comment: As a start, check the output of this command `lslpp -l | grep Java8` You should see version number `8.0.0.526` or higher.

Comment: Yes I could see the version number as 8.0.0.527.

Comment: I did more R&D and found that it is IBM Java which is not allowing communication over TLS 1.2. The same handshake failure was observed on Linux with IBM Java, though it was successful with Oracle Java.

Do you have any idea how to enable TLS 1.2 on IBM Java 8?

Comment: Compile and run this program: `public class AES_keylen { static public void main (String args []) throws Exception { int maxaeskeylen= javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES"); System.out.println ("MaxAesKeyLen="+maxaeskeylen); } }`; the result should be `2147483647`. Also you could say something about your server-program -- so far you haven't disclosed any details (it might be TomCat but that's only a guess based on the 8443 port.)

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten using this option:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Or from code, at startup

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Comment: I have already tried these options, but still not able to communicate over TLS 1.2. Is there any other property specific to IBM java which can be used here?

Comment: Do you realize that you haven't said anything about your application (other than OS and JRE versions)?

Comment: This is about a Spring application which uses Jetty as server engine to start the application service. It uses Java 1.8, so while starting the service, I can provide the option suggested by you (-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2) but somehow it is not enforcing TLS 1.2.  One more point to notice here is when I run the application on Linux OS with Oracle Java, it worked fine but on the same Linux OS, it failed with IBM Java. So, I am suspecting, there is some property specific to IBM Java which is restricting the communication over TLS 1.2